# Parallax webpage darken image but not text

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, parallax

I am creating a parallax webpage with 3 images on it however I want the image to be darken and the texts to not be but when I adjust filter brightness the whole thing is darkened. I have also added columns to my 3rd page but it seems that having the columns keeps it unaligned and having the bottom left hand not aligned with the rest of the text. 
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPTE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Web Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="pimg1">
            <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="Intro"><strong>Intro </strong></h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pimg2">
        <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="openSans"><strong>Who am I</strong></h1> <br>
            <p> Words and stuff
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pimg3">
        <div class="ptext">
                <h1 class="openSans"><strong>How I Work</strong></h1>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-search" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Research</h2>
                    <p>Words.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-flask" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Design</h2>
                                        <p>Words.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-code" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Build</h2>
                                      <p>Words.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <i class="fas fa-retweet" style="color:#1d5ba0; padding: 10px"></i>
                    <h2>Refine </h2>
                                       <p>Words.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400px;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color:#666;
}
.pimg1, .pimg2, .pimg3{
    position:relative;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    filter:brightness(50%);

  }
.pimg1{
    background-image:url('../img/image1.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}
.pimg2{
    background-image:url('../img/image2.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}
.pimg3{
    background-image:url('../img/image3.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
}

.ptext{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    font-size: 40px;
 }

 h1{
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-block-start: auto;
    margin-block-end: auto;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

.openSans {
    font-family: Open Sans!important;
    color:white;
}

h1.Intro{
    font-family: Open Sans!important;
    color:white;
    margin-block-start: -3em;
}

h2{
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-block-start: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 35em;
    text-align: center;
}
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 47%;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've almost answered it yourself. If you want to adjust the brightness on the image and not the text you can't adjust the "whole thing". You'll need to make sure the image and the text are separate in html and then adjust the image alone using its id or class.

For example: you might have a

```
<div id="allinone">text</div>
```

that has the image assigned within css. to separate them you'd instead want:

```
<div id="notallinone">
     text
    <img class="darkenedImg" src="yourimageurl.png"/>
</div>
```

Where you can add styles to the #notallinone and .darkenedImg css blocks separately

Comment: I tried doing that but when I do the image gets removed or all the text goes to the top of the first page not on each separate one

Comment: Can you post your code with the image separate? It's unlikely that it gets removed. If you're using chrome, when you are looking at your website in browser you can press Ctrl + Shift + i and you'll be able to look through the HTML elements, and when you hover over the image you'll be able to see where it is, and what dimensions it has. If the little hover text says 0 x 0 then it is possible that you'll need to set the width and height attributes of the div.

Comment: Each image/text pair should be in a separate div, and if they are then you can control when they're seen as a unit by adjusting the opacity or z-index of the image/text's parent divs. If the text is at the top, you'll have to give some CSS to the <p> element to change that, such as 

#parentdiv p {
    margin-top: calc( 50% - 22px);
}

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified that I'd need you to post the code as an update to your question, I can't download something like that on my work computer for security reasons.

Comment: So post the updated code with the divs you mentioned?

Comment: or I can post the drive link again since its after hours

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. In general you'll get more participation if you post your code all on this page. I'm glad you found a work around, though being able to style elements separately will certainly be needed again. Definitely worth it to keep trying and experimenting! Just remember that if you want a certain style to happen, and you think you've assigned the style correctly, look at if it's an inheritance issue. You can sometimes check that by placing "!important" between the desired style value and the semicolon and seeing if there's a change. Also, the browser inspector is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to darken the image and then upload to my workspace which does the same thing